# Infinite system of linear equations (Vandermonde matrix)

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations

Is it true that if
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{a_k^nt_k}=0 $$
for all $ n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\} $ and some fixed sequence $ \{a_k\}_{1\le k\le \infty},\,a_k\ne a_l \ \forall k\ne l $, then $ t_k=0 \ \forall k $? Do conditions like $ 0\le a_k \le 1$ and $ -1\le t_k\le 1 $ change the answer?

**Edit.** I understood that there is an interesting reformulation of this question: to prove (or refute) that this infinite system of linear equations
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & \dots \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & \dots & a_n & \dots \\
a_1^2 & a_2^2 & a_3^2 & \dots & a_n^2 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_1^k & a_2^k & a_3^k & \dots & a_n^k & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
t_1 \\ t_2 \\ t_3 \\ \vdots \\ t_n \\ \vdots 
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ \vdots 
\end{pmatrix} $$
has no nontrivial solutions for $ t_i $. Although probably linear algebra isn't applicable here, since left matrix doesn't determine linear transformation due to divergence of series.